# NestJS How to catch exception from inner function

Tags: nestjs

When the API Endpoint server is unavailable, the `ApiCallerService.post` should return 404. How can I catch the error in AppController when the 404 HttpException is threw from `ApiCallService`?
Now once the exception is threw from `ApiCallerService.post`, the application crashed.

AppController:

```
export class AppController {
    constructor(
        private apiCallerService: ApiCallerService
    ) {}

    @UseFilters(new NoExceptionFilter())
    @MessagePattern(TEST_TOPIC)
    readCreationMessage(@Payload() message) {
        try {
            const data = message.value.data;
            const payload = {
                name: data.name
            };
            this.apiCallerService.post(ENDPOINTS.TEST_ENDPOINT, payload);
            
        } catch (exception) {
            Logger.log("Exception caught here :)");
        }
    }
}
```

ApiCallerService:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiCallerService {
    constructor(
        private httpService: HttpService,
    ) {}

    post(path: string, data: any): Observable<AxiosResponse> {
        const response = this.httpService
            .post(`${path}`, data)
            .pipe(
                catchError((e) => {
                    Logger.log('Exception', e);
                    throw new HttpException(e.response.data, e.response.status);
                }),
            );
        response.subscribe((d: AxiosResponse) =>
            console.log(`Response for endpoint ${path}`, d),
        );
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example try/catch works only for synchronous operations, but

```js
this.apiCallerService.post(ENDPOINTS.TEST_ENDPOINT, payload);
```

returns `Observable<AxiosResponse>` - this is async operation. Depending on the version of `rxjs` you are working with, you need to read the relevant documentation on how to catch errors.